# How do i update a value in a specific record?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I know how to update a value which is by using

```
cursor.execute(f"UPDATE main SET Points = {winner_updated_points} WHERE Points = {old_winner_points}")
```

but i want it to be from a specific user's id, for example the id of the winner is 322. I want it to updated the points of id 322 but i cant seem to figure out how

Answer (score 1):

You can use a prepared statement in which placeholders for parameters are securely defined by question marks, and counterpart values for those placeholders are ordered respectively with a tuple such as

```
sql  = """
          UPDATE main
             SET points = ?
           WHERE id = ?
       """

cursor.execute(sql,(<some value>,322,))
con.commit()
```